# How to align cells to be in the same position as its headercell

Tags: c#, pdf

I have been working on an application that creates a pdf with a table displayed on it.
The problem is, that i can create cells and header cells, but they dont align on the horizontal axis, thus causing problems while reading.
[Table on the PDF with wrong formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CgRD.png)

this is the C# code. PS I use the Nuget package PDF Quest

```
void ComposeTable(IContainer container)
{
    var headerStyle = TextStyle.Default.SemiBold();

    container.Decoration(decoration =>
    {
        // header
        decoration.Header().BorderBottom(1).Padding(5).Row(row =>
        {
            row.ConstantColumn(25).Text("#", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn(3).Text("1", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("2", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("3", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("4", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("5", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("6", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("7", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("8", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("9", headerStyle);
            row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text("10", headerStyle);
        });

        // content
        decoration
            .Content()
            .Stack(column =>
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Items)
                {
                    column.Item().ShowEntire().BorderBottom(1).BorderColor(Colors.Grey.Lighten2).Padding(5).Row(row =>
                    {
                        row.ConstantColumn(25).Text(Model.Items.IndexOf(item) + 1);
                        row.RelativeColumn(3).Text(item.Name);
                        row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price}$");
                        row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text(item.Quantity);
                        row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price * item.Quantity}$");
                        row.RelativeColumn(3).Text(item.Name);
                        row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price}$");
                        row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text(item.Quantity);
                        row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price * item.Quantity}$");
                        row.RelativeColumn(3).Text(item.Name);
                        row.RelativeColumn().AlignRight().Text($"{item.Price}$");

                    });
                   
                }
    
            });

    });

}
```

Comment: The link you posted seems to be broken.

Comment: I never used PDF Quest but as I was reading your question I noticed that : in your header you have only 1 row with `RelativeColumn(3)` and all other are `RelativeColumn()`, but in your body you have 3 rows with `RelativeColumn(3)`. Couldn't that be the problem?

Comment: Yes that was the problem! My boss gave it to me like this and i thought it would be right, but actually you are right, thank you:)